# Coulomb gauge covariance

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, covariance, gauge

Why do we say Coulomb gauge is not covariant, whereas Lorenz gauge is? What's the ultimate reason why Coulomb gauge cannot be covariant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Coulomb Gauge is

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{A} = \partial_xA^x \partial_y A^y \partial_z A^z = 0$$

The Lorentz Gauge is

$$\partial _\mu A^\mu = 0$$

Any equation which can be put into the form of a pair of contracted Lorentz indices, one up and one down, as in the Lorentz gauge, maintains its form upon Lorentz transformation. Thus the Lorentz Gauge condition keeps its form in any reference frame.

On the other hand, the Coulomb Gauge is "missing" the $-\partial_t A^t$ term, and without this time component that was necessary to contract the Lorentz index, it no longer maintains its form in another reference frame. This means one must choose which frame to impose the Coulomb Gauge in, and transformations to other frames will break the condition.

Let's see how the Coulomb Gauge *does* transform. We know that

$$A'^\mu = \Lambda^\mu _{\,\,\nu}A^\nu$$

$$\partial'_\mu = \Lambda_\mu ^{\,\,\nu}\partial_\nu$$

For the Coulomb Gauge, though, we only need the transformation laws for the three components $i=1,2,3$ (standing for $x,y,z$). Still the sum over $\nu =0,1,2,3$ (standing for $t,x,y,z$) persists:

$$A'^i = \Lambda^i _{\,\,\nu}A^\nu = \Lambda^i _{\,\,0}A^0 + \Lambda^i _{\,\,1}A^1+\Lambda^i _{\,\,2}A^2+\Lambda^i _{\,\,3}A^3$$

And for the partial derivatives similarly:

$$\partial'_i = \Lambda_i ^{\,\,\nu}\partial_\nu = \Lambda_i ^{\,\,0}\partial_0 + \Lambda_i ^{\,\,1}\partial_1+\Lambda_i ^{\,\,2}\partial_2+\Lambda_i ^{\,\,3}\partial_3$$

I think at this point, I need not plug the 2 above equations into $(\partial_i A^i)'$ to make the point: You can see already that you get these terms with $A_0$ and $\partial_0$. These have no place in the Coulomb Gauge!! The equation will not hold the same form in another reference frame.